# Getting notified when user arrives and leaves specific location (Android and iOS)

Tags: android, ios, iphone, location, mobile-application

My final goal is to calculate how much time a user is spending at a specific location. Therefore I would like to make the application aware of when a user arrives and leaves a specific location, so I can calculate the time spent there.

Is there a way to get notified when a user arrived at specific location and leaves it in Android and iOS? It does not need to be instant, one-two minutes of miscalculation are fine.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On Android platform, your can try the [Geofencing API](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) introduced at Google I/O 2013

Within the API document, they provide a good [example project](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/GeofenceDetection.zip).

Answer (score 1):

And for iOS it's called (surprisingly) [Location Services](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDcQFjAC&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/LocationAwarenessPG.pdf&ei=m5zfUs2xHomN0AXf74HICA&usg=AFQjCNHW2PTuSM9BudVXM5geWebXnqCtJw&sig2=drvMWlH-Gowz7Wt3c-F1zg&bvm=bv.59568121,d.d2k) - what you need is the Region Monitoring.